# I want to trigger a function when the app gets added to slack

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want to send an onboarding flow to the user when they add the app to their slack. And, I am using slack bolt.

I tried using callbackOptions, but I get this error:

> res is not a function

Here is the code that I tried:

```
callbackOptions: {
    success: (installation, installOptions, req, res) => {
        // Do custom success logic here
        res.send('successful!');
    }, 
    failure: (error, installOptions , req, res) => {
        // Do custom failure logic here
        res.send('failure');
    }
}
```

How can I make it work, or is there any other option to achieve this?